# Preventing multiple loading of large objects in uWSGI workers?

Tags: python, uwsgi

I have one very large custom data structure (similar to a trie, though it's not important to the question) that I'm using to access and serve data from. I'm moving my application to uWSGI for production use now, and I definitely don't want this reloaded per worker. Can I share it among worker processes somehow? I just load the structure once and then reload it once a minute through apscheduler. Nothing any of the workers do modify the data structure in any way. Is there another better solution to this type of problem? Loading the same thing per worker is hugely wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the kind of data structure it is, you could try using a memory mapped file. There is a [Python library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) that wraps the relevant system calls.

The file's structure would need to reflect the data structure you are using. For example, if you need a trie, you could store all of the strings in a sorted list and do a binary search for the prefix to see which strings have that prefix.

As you access pages in the file, they will be loaded into memory via the OS's disk read cache. Subsequent requests for the same page will be fast. Because the disk cache can be shared between processes, all of your UWSGI workers will benefit from the speed of accessing cached pages.

I tried this on Linux by forcing it to scan a big file in two separate processes. Create a large file called 'big', then run the following in two separate Python processes:

```
import mmap
with open('big') as fp:
    map = mmap.mmap(fp.fileno(), 0, mmap.MAP_PRIVATE)
    if x == 'a':  # Make sure 'a' doesn't occur in the file!
        break
```

You will notice that the resident memory of the two processes grows as they scan the file, however, so does the shared memory usage. For example, if `big` is a 1 gb file, both processes will appear to be using about 1 gb of memory. However, the overall memory load on the system will be increased by only 1 gb, not 2 gb.

Obviously there are some limitations to this approach, chiefly that the data structure you are looking to share is easily represented in a binary format. Also, Python needs to copy any bytes from the file into memory whenever you access them. This can cause aggressive garbage collection if you frequently read through the entire file in small pieces, or undermine the shared memory benefit of the memory map if you read large pieces.